# Apostrophes getting sent as \'

Tags: php, html

```
function send_mails($adress, $subject, $message, &$tpl)
{

    // fix for correct display of newlines and spaces in the message
    $textmail = ereg_replace( "\n", "\r\n", $message);
    $textmail = wordwrap($textmail, 70, "\r\n");

    //prepare text to show online (html)
    $textshow = ereg_replace( "\r\n", "<br>", $textmail);

    $sent = '-- HTML Code to show the Mail you sent --';

    $tpl->assign(BODY, $sent);

    $mailtext = utf8_decode($textmail);

    $headers = '-- Functional Header --'; 

    mail ($adress, $subject, $mailtext, $headers);
}
```

My problem now is that if the message contains apostrophes they're show like this:

> We\'re too good, so you shouldn\'t judge this example text\'s content

I've tried `$textmail = ereg_replace(" \' ", " ' ", $textmail);` but that didn't seem to work.

I'm pretty sure there is an easy fix, but I've been looking for some time now and haven't found a solution... Probably searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: Try `$textmail = ereg_replace("\\'", "'", $textmail);`

Comment: Just curious: what does `<?php var_dump(phpversion(), ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'), ini_get('magic_quotes_runtime'));` print on that machine?

Comment: Why isn't "shouldn't" escaped.......? Have you checked at which step apostrophes are being added?

Comment: Forgot to add the \ in shouldn't... It was just an example text I typed in...

Comment: @VolkerK: string(5) "5.2.6" string(1) "1" string(0) ""

Comment: So magic_quotes_gpc is on. Please have a read of http://docs.php.net/magic_quotes - the answer you've accepted (it's not wrong; I'm saying this with all the love in the world ;-)) is treating a symptom, not the underlying cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string stripslashes ( string $str )` is what you are looking for!

```
$str = "We\'re too good, so you shouldn't judge this example text\'s content";

$newStr = stripslashes ( $str );

echo $newStr;
```

Output:

`We're too good, so you shouldn't judge this example text's content`

---

**EDIT**

VolkerK's comment:

> I think it might be useful to first determine
>   whether this would fight the cause or just a symptom...

Please consider, that this is kind of Hot-Fix, you should try to find out, how and where this is actually happening?

Does `$message` at the beginning contain these slashes? (just `echo` it.)

- If yes, where does `$message` come from?
- If not, go through it all the way `$message`-> `$textmail` -> `$textshow` … and find out, which step does it and eliminate it there!

Comment: I think it might be useful to first determine whether this would fight the cause or just a symptom...

Comment: You are absolutely right! I will add that to the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I've now implemented stripslashes() and it's (obv.) working.

For looking into the source: $message does already contain the slashes... I get it from a textarea

Comment: Yes it is! But keep the **Edit** of my answer and also what VolkerK wrote in mind! I hope I could help you!

Comment: As for the source of the slashes, anyone got an idea? It gets it via a textarea and posts it to my mail sending script which then uses it for the send_mails()-function...

Comment: So you get it, before sending it to the function  `send_mails`? Where does it come from then? Try to `echo` it the line before you call `send_mails` and check if there are already the apostrophes.

Comment: Yup, echoing $message before the call of send_mails shows that there are already \' s in there...

Comment: Ok, then go up and echo `$message` after (and maybe before) any operation you did with it. Then you should be able to locate the operation which adds the slashes!

Comment: That "operation" is magic_quotes_gpc, so the damage is already done before the first line of the script(s) is executed ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK: Is there a better fix then than the stripslashes?